# Squared arrows within equations & creativity

Tags: arrows, tikz-arrows

I wrote the equation below, but something I have not been able to manage is the type of arrow I am using to shows an iterative procedure. I would like to make it at least bigger because is currently too small. This equation goes for a scientific poster, where creativity is highly appreciated, so if besides the size you also know a way to change the normal arrow to a 'cool' arrow, is also appreciated. Thanks!

(I am compiling it in LuaLatex)

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}

\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikzsymbols}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{bigints}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}
\tikzset{square arrow/.style={to path={-- ++(0,-2.25)  -| (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes},below,pos=3.75}}

\begin{document}

 \[  Q(\theta | \tikzmark{a}{\theta_{(i)}}) = \bigint\limits_{\{ {\small \Springtree, \Autumntree, \Summertree,...} \}} logL(\theta|\Wintertree) d\Wintertree \longrightarrow \tikzmark{b}{\theta_{(i+1)}} = \displaystyle\argmax_{\theta} Q(\theta | \theta_{(i)} ) \] 

\tikz[overlay,remember picture]
{\draw[->,square arrow] (b.south) to (a.south);}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With some small changes of your math setting (not essential to arrow, but correct typesetting of math operators and smashed integral limit) I obtain the following result:

[image]

is this what you looking for?

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}

\usepackage{mathtools, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{tikzsymbols}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{bigints}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};
                          }
\tikzset{square arrow/.style={%
    -{Stealth[length=3mm]},rounded corners,draw=red,%
    to path={-- ++(0,-1.5) -| (\tikztotarget)}}
                                }


\begin{document}
\[
Q(\theta | \tikzmark{a}{\theta_{(i)}})
    = \smashoperator[r]{\bigint_{\{\small
                           \Springtree, \Autumntree, \Summertree, \dots \}}
                        }
    \log L(\theta|\Wintertree) \mathrm{d}\Wintertree \longrightarrow 
           \tikzmark{b}{\theta_{(i+1)}} 
    = \displaystyle\argmax_{\theta} Q\left(\theta | \theta_{(i)}\right)
\]

\tikz[overlay,remember picture]
{\draw[square arrow] (b.south) to (a.south);}

\end{document}
```

I use pdfLaTeX and for showed result the minimum two successive compilation are necessary.

**Edit:**
an alternative, inspired by *gernot* solution, but with slightly different approach:

- arrow's head is defined as before by help of `arrows.meta` library
- for bending of arrows is used library `topaths`. The bend is defined with option `bend left=60`
- part of equation, which are connected by arrows, are highlighted by red color
- `\tikzmarks` are moved into variable indices, so no adjustment of it's start, end and lengths is not necessary.

[image]

Complete MWE with marked changes is:

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
\usepackage{mathtools, amsthm, amssymb}% <-- amsmath replaced with mathtools
\usepackage{tikzsymbols}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,topaths}% <-- new
\usepackage{bigints}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};
                          }

\tikzset{loop arrow/.style={% <-- new
    -{Stealth[length=5mm]}, ultra thick, draw=red!40,
    bend left=60}}

\begin{document}
\[
Q(\theta | \textcolor{red}{\theta_{(i\tikzmark{a})}})% <-- changed
    = \smashoperator[r]{\bigint_{\{\small
                           \Springtree, \Autumntree, \Summertree, \dots \}}
                        }
    \log L(\theta|\Wintertree) \mathrm{d}\Wintertree \longrightarrow
           \textcolor{red}{\theta_{(i\tikzmark{b}+1)}}% <-- changed
    = \displaystyle\argmax_{\theta} Q\left(\theta | \theta_{(i)}\right)
\]

\tikz[overlay,remember picture]
{\draw[loop arrow] (b.south) to  (a.south);}% <-- changed

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

To obtain something like this:

[image]

I use the following code

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikzsymbols}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{myarrow/.style={->,>=Stealth[open],shorten >=3pt,shorten <=3pt,thick}}
\usepackage{bigints}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[3][0ex]%
   {\tikz[baseline=#1,remember picture]
       \node[outer sep=0mm,inner sep=0mm,minimum width=0mm] (#2) {#3};%
   }
\begin{document}
 \[  Q(\theta | \tikzmark[-0.28ex]{a}{$\theta_{(i)}$})
     = \bigint\limits_{\{ \mbox{\small \Springtree, \Autumntree, \Summertree,...} \}}
       \hspace{-1.5em}
       \log L(\theta|\Wintertree) d\Wintertree
    \tikz[baseline=-0.8ex]\draw[myarrow] (0,0) -- (1,0);
    \tikzmark[-0.28ex]{b}{$\theta_{(i+1)}$}
     = \displaystyle\argmax_{\theta} Q(\theta | \theta_{(i)} )
 \] 
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]%
  {\draw[myarrow] (b.south) to[out=-70,in=-110] (a.south);
  }
\end{document}
```

I added the following things.

```
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
```

allows you to draw nicer arrows; its options are documented in the tikz manual. I use it for the `Stealth` arrow tip.

```
\tikzset{myarrow/.style={->,>=Stealth[open],shorten >=3pt,shorten <=3pt,thick}}
```

This collects the style elements common to the arrows under the name `myarrow`. `->` says that it should end with a tip, `>=Stealth[open]` defines the form of the tip, and the two `shorten` keys say that the arrows should start in a distance of 3pt and end 3pt before the goal.

```
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[3][0ex]{...}
```

The command has now three parameters: The first one is optional and allows us to shift the baseline of the node up and down (the positioning needs experimenting). The second parameter is the name of the node as before, and the third one is the contents of the node. Putting something into the node allows us to let the arrow start e.g. centered below the item.

```
 \log
```

Assuming that `log` refers to the logarithm, I changed it to `\log`.

```
 \mbox{\small \Springtree, \Autumntree, \Summertree,...}
```

`\small` should appear in text mode (LaTex complained about it before).

```
 \hspace{-1.5em}
```

Removes some of the space between integral and formula.

```
 \tikz[baseline=-0.8ex]\draw[myarrow] (0,0) -- (1,0);
```

Draws the inline arrow with tikz to use the same style.

```
 \draw[myarrow] (b.south) to[out=-70,in=-110] (a.south);
```

The `out` and `in` parameter give the direction in which the arrow should start and end, respectively, measured in degrees counter-clockwise from the positive x-axis.

Comment: Regarding `\hspace`, see Zarko's solution for a more elegant approach (`\smashoperator[r]`).